# Binary Search advanced template explain

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

I was learning the Binary Search template II on Leetcode. https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/126/template-ii/937/

```py
def binarySearch(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left == right
    if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
        return left
    return -1
```

It is said that key attributes of this template including

- Search Condition needs to access element's immediate right neighbor
- Use element's right neighbor to determine if condition is met and decide whether to go left or right
- Gurantees Search Space is at least 2 in size at each step

I didn't understand how the code "access element's immediate right neighbor" or use it to "determine if condition is met and decide whether to go left or right".

How does that work?

Comment: Does your question concern the code or the explanation of the writer ?

Comment: Given the unnecessary post processing (when we reach that point we are already sure the record is not there), I assume the algorithm was previously written a bit differently. So the explanation may have made sense back then.

Comment: That explanation on LeetCode doesn't make sense to me either. I could think of much better explanations. For instance, one key difference with Template 1, which is not listed, is that the range being looked at *includes* index `right`, while in Template 1, it *excludes* `right`.

Comment: my question is about the explanation, but the logic of the code also confused me. How does including index right in the range enhance the algorithm for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the explanation is garbage. No wonder they hid the Binary Search section on the Explore page making it available [via a direct link](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/) only, but maybe my comment will help someone.

As far as I understand, what they meant is, you can safely inspect the `nums[mid + 1]` element since the search space is guaranteed to be at least 2 in size. You can check out the official solution for the [Find Minimum in Rotated Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-minimum-in-rotated-sorted-array/) problem (it's available without the Premium). The core idea there is to see if we are greater than the very next (`mid + 1`th) item, and I think this is the approach the 2nd template implies.

Beware though, there is a bug in the official solution (yeah, totally not cool), so refer to the discussion section if you decide to dive into this, there's a good post on it there.